# facing issue while running powershell commands in cmd using qprocess in qt

Tags: powershell, qt, cmd, qthread, qprocess

I need to run a powershell script in cmd using qt qprocess.

my final command should be powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File  D:/
here D:/ is argument to script.
I am trying to execute this by Qprocess:startDetached but its not working.

```
enter code here
```

```
bool ConfigScriptExecutor::StartScriptFile(const std::string& script, const std::string& scriptArgs)
    {
        qint64 pid = 0;
        QString processName = "cmd.exe";
        QStringList arguments;
        std::string Powershell_unrestriced_command = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ";
        arguments << Powershell_unrestriced_command.c_str();
        arguments << fs::system_complete(script).string().c_str();
        if (!scriptArgs.empty())
        {
            arguments << scriptArgs.c_str();
        }
        QString workingDir(FileSystemHelper::ApplicationPath().c_str());

        Debug::Output(make_string() << "Executing process: " << processName.toStdString()
            << " " << arguments[0].toStdString()
            << " workingDir: " << workingDir.toStdString());

        bool success = QProcess::startDetached(processName, arguments, workingDir, &pid);

        return (success && pid != 0);

}
```

Comment: If you're calling via `cmd.exe`, you need the `/c` parameter to pass a command line to execute. That said, calling `powershell.exe` directly should suffice.

Comment: Why is `QProcess` used to start with the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` which should next start also with using `CreateProcess` the executable `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`? That makes absolutely no sense as it requires to fulfill the C++ syntax, the `QProcess` internal processing of the arguments, the syntax of `cmd.exe` and the syntax of `PowerShell.exe`.

Comment: Use `QString qsPowerShellFileName = qEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot", QStringLiteral("C:\\Windows")) + QStringLiteral("\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe");` to get the fully qualified file name of PowerShell and run `qsPowerShellFileName` using `QProcess`. There is no need to make use of the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` at all. But I don't understand what a C++ coded program using Qt cannot do what can be done with a PowerShell script interpreted by PowerShell. Everything `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` can do can be done with C++ code too.

Comment: @mklement0 Hi, where to use /c in below lines.
arguments << Powershell_unrestriced_command.c_str();
        arguments << fs::system_complete(script).string().c_str();
        if (!scriptArgs.empty())
        {
            arguments << scriptArgs.c_str();//argumenst are here only
        }

Comment: Prepend `/c` to your `"powershell ..."` string (`"/c powershell ..."`) but - again - there is no need to call via `cmd.exe`;  therefore, consider replacing `QString processName = "cmd.exe";` with `QString processName = "powershell.exe";` (or specify the full path, as Mofi suggests).